# Are there any legit reasons why PHP's "HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR" or "HTTP_CLIENT_IP" would be different from "REMOTE_ADDR"?

Tags: php, header, http-headers, ip, security

I'd like to implement certain security and other features for users in certain geographical areas. I'm aware that the "HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR" and "HTTP_CLIENT_IP" can be faked, but are there any actual legitimate reasons why they would even be in the header, or otherwise different from REMOTE_ADDR? Can anyone give any examples?

If I allow my service to only those that have matching IPs, or empty forwarded IP values, would I be leaving any legitimate customers out that are not trying to bypass IP location security?

Answer (score 2):

Non-anonymous proxies might add those headers. AOL used to do this some years ago for example.

However, you **cannot trust them under any circumstances** unless *you* control the system adding them. And in this case you need to ensure that the headers are only used in case the request's `REMOTE_ADDR` is actually one of those systems. And those systems must *always* add the header and/or ensure that it's properly replaced in case a client already sends one.

Comment: I'm not quite sure this answered my question. Are you saying that REMOTE_ADDR can also not be trusted? Isn't that the IP of the actual computer doing the request? What I was really asking is if I should block someone whose REMOTE_ADDR and HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR are different from each other. Thanks.